# Azure ACS Authentication not working after I publish

Tags: authentication, azure, cloud, acs

I configured google logins for our application. However I need your help yet again, I can get it to work locally but after I deploy it doesn’t.

To give you a little bit more detail what I do to deploy is:

I configure in the Relying party applications a new instance with a link to

> http://blabla.cloudapp.net/

Everything else I keep the same.

Then I go to my webconfig in my application and change the realm code:

```
<audienceUris>
    <add value="http://127.0.0.1:81/" />
    <add value="http://blabla.cloudapp.net/" />
  </audienceUris>
  <federatedAuthentication>
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://blabla.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation" realm=" http://blabla.cloudapp.net/" requireHttps="false" />
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
  </federatedAuthentication>
```

I set up all my references as copy to local and I run publish. If I now go to my cloudsite I notice that no authentication actually happens. It seems it is just skipped

I tried to log in the VM and see if anything happens but I don't see anything.
If i go to the web.config located on the VM i only see this code inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" validation="SHA1" validationKey="FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

(keys are not the originals ones of course)

Are there any other options I could persue? I don't really get it

Comment: provide the `authentication` and `authorization` sections of your web.config! Within `authorization` you must have `<deny users="?" />` and `authentication` is typically set to `none` by the Identity and Access tool. Also provide versions of Visual Studio, .NET Framework used and osFamily configured for the WebRole.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `realm` is configured on Relying Party side in ACS. If you set `realm` in your web.config, which is not the same as `realm` in configured Relying Party application in ACS, your setup will not work!

Secondly, you have an extra space in your web.config exactly at the `realm` attribute, it is:

> realm=" http://blabla.cloudapp.net/"

but should be

> realm="http://blabla.cloudapp.net/"

Note the additional blank space you have before `http://...`

Make sure you have the same `realm` values in your web.config and in your Relying Party application!

A suggestion - provide exact ACS errors, as thus we have better chance for helping you!

Comment: The name I used is the same as the relying party, I don't know why u would think otherwise. I described that I created it :) And the space is just a typo, it's not in my real webconfig, my apologies.
How do I provide exact ACS errors? I don't have any errors, the login screen just isn't hit and it automatically directs to my webpage